# python polynomial fit with some coefficients being fixed, order should be a parameter, need to create list of variables?

Tags: python, curve-fitting, polynomials

I need some help writing a pretty simple code (at least in pseudo code):

I want fit data using a polynomial of order `n`, where n is a parameter and should be changable. On top of that I would like to always keep the first three coefficients fixed to be zero. So I need something like

```
order = 5
def poly(x,c0=0,c1=0,c2=0,c3,c4,c5):
    return numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyval(x, [c0,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5], tensor=False)
popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(poly,x,y)
```

So problems I can not sove atm is:

How do I create a polynomial function with `n` number of coefficents? I basicly need to create a list of variables of length `n`.

If that is solved than we could put `c0` to `c2` to `0`.

I hope I was able to make myself clear, if not please help me to refine my question.

Answer (score 1):

You currently do not keep the first 3 coefficient fixed to 0, you just give them a default value.

Arbitrary argument lists seem to be what you are looking for:

```
def poly(x,*args):
        return numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyval(x, [0,0,0] + list(args), tensor=False)
```

If the number of arguments MUST be of fixed length (for instance `n`), you can check len(args) and raise an error if necessary.

Calling `poly(x,a,b,c)` now returns the polynomial function with the coefficients `[0,0,0,a,b,c]`

You can find more information in Python's documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions

Comment: You will need to write `(0,0,0) + args` or `[0,0,0] + list(args)` otherwise you get `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list`.

Comment: I see, but I would like to create a polynomial function without having to specify arguments `a,b,c...`, because for a polynomial of let us say order 22, to write all the variables will be tedious.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, where would you get your coefficients from?